# Windows 10 and starting a program as administrator

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, administrator, runas

How to run program as administrator and how to run it normally in Windows 10 by simple clicking when you are logged as administrator? (this is my first question, so feel free to correct it)

Comment: If you don't have administrator rights you cannot start an application with administrator rights.  Your answer requires you authenticate an Administrator user....

Comment: use Task Scheduler to workaround the UAC: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=135472

Answer (score -1):

We can run as administrator simply by right clicking on the shortcut and clicking "Run as administrator".

Another possibility is to change properties of the shortcut so that right clicking is not necessary. The steps to do this are as follows:

1. Right click on the program (shortcut)
2. Click on Properties
3. Navigate to the Shortcut tab and find "Choose enhanced properties of this shortcut"
4. Click on Advanced...
5. Check Run as administrator
6. Click OK twice
7. (Optional) Rename the shortcut to know it runs under administrator rights

Previous method can make two independent shortcuts. 
Another option:
Note that following method changes rights to the whole program, so you cannot have two independent shortcuts for a single program. If you just want to run program as administrator by right clicking, that is also valid option. The below changes rights to all shortcuts of the program.

1. Right click on the program (shortcut)
2. Click on Properties
3. Navigate to the Compatibility tab
4. Check Run this program as administrator
5. Click OK